# Ltspice digital look up table

Tags: ltspice, spice

Can't find digital LUT model (look up table) for Ltspice. I'd like to have some configurable LUT. For my application, I need 5 in / 1 out.

I tried to create one myself, but it's not that easy, as I thought.

Where can I get a configurable digital LUT? Or how to build it?
If I have to do it with multiple and/or: how can I make the model configurable?

Edit:  I used LtSpice, Not Spice.

Comment: it's been awhile, but from the top of my head: SPICE in its original form doesn't do digital simulation, so you're using some XSPIC/HSPICE... or other implementation, and just from a tingle in my fingertips, I'd assume the specific software you're using might be of relevance here.

Comment: Check out section 12.4 of the [ngspice user manual](http://ngspice.sourceforge.net/docs/ngspice-manual.pdf)

Comment: 12.4. of the manual is a digital LUT, exactly what I was looking för. Thanks. Upvoted. I will try ngspice.

Comment: @SteKulov Bring on the champagne, you've been upvoted!

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen Hahaha.  It's my finest hour, so I'll crack open the one that doesn't come in a plastic bottle.